# What does "fuoritutto" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

I see `fuoritutto` in many adverts, for example [here](https://www.massbike.it/promozione-fuori-tutto-pronta-consegna/). Does this mean something like "Everything must go"?

The [only dictionary](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/F/fuoritutto.aspx?query=fuoritutto) that I found lists this word has the meaning `Lunghezza massima di una imbarcazione misurata tra i punti estremi della prua e della poppa`, which has nothing to do with the adverts.

Comment: Note that there's a small but significant difference between *fuori tutto* and *fuoritutto* :)

Comment: It doesn't look like that difference is always maintained. See https://www.mediashopping.it/it-IT-it/Attributo_Fuoritutto_MS02.aspx for example. Or https://www.webnews.it/2018/08/02/unieuro-fuoritutto-sconti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's right, the meaning is precisely “Everything must go”.

Only, mind that, unlike the nautical term, in ads “fuori tutto” is generally, apart from humorous or quirky uses, spelt in two words, literally “everything (has to go) outside”.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common expression in italian advertising that means that there is a huge discount sale going on, for example because of ceased activity or stock renewal.